# How to build a binary tree from a given interface

Tags: sorting, search, interface, binary-tree

I need to build a simple binary tree, which includes Person elements.
Persons must be sorted by height(from low to high). If there are two people with same height, but different sex, men should be first. Usually we use left and right nodes of the element. How can I build tree otherways?

Here is how persons are created:

```
Person john = new Person() {
    @Override
    public boolean isMale() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return 175;
    }
};
```

This is an interface:

```
public interface Person {
    public int getID();
    public boolean isMale();
    public int getHeight();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any examples you have tried?

Comment: Possibly you can use some predefined type of a tree container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Full code with test class](https://github.com/InQuirer/ITI0050-Algoritmid-ja-andmestruktuurid-2015/tree/master/HW01)

Node.java

```
public class Node {
    double key = 0;
    Node parent = null, left = null, right = null;
    IDancer dancer = null;
    public Node(IDancer d) {
        this.dancer = d;
        String key = d.getHeight() +  (d.isMale() ? "0." : "1.") + d.getID();
        this.key = Double.parseDouble(key);
        System.out.println("new node: " + this.key);
    }
    public void copy(double key, IDancer d) {
        this.dancer = d;
        this.key = key;
    }
    public boolean hasRight() {
        if (this.right != null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean hasLeft() {
        if (this.left != null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean hasParent() {
        if (this.parent != null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean isMale() {
        if (this.dancer.isMale())
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Dancers.java

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Dancers implements IDancers {
    public Tree tree = new Tree();
    @Override
    public SimpleEntry<IDancer, IDancer> findPartnerFor(IDancer d) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(d instanceof IDancer) ||
            (d.getHeight() <= 0) ||
            (d.getID() <= 0)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        IDancer partner = null;
        tree.insert(d);
        try {partner = (d.isMale()) ? tree.female(d) : tree.male(d);
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {return null;}
        if (partner != null) {
            tree.remove(d);
            tree.remove(partner);
            System.err.println("Partner: "
                    + d.getID() 
                    + (d.isMale() ? "M " : "F ") 
                    + " For: " 
                    + partner.getID() 
                    + (partner.isMale() ? "M " : "F "));
            return new SimpleEntry<IDancer, IDancer>(d, partner);
        } return null;
    }
    @Override
    public List<IDancer> returnWaitingList() {
        try {return tree.inorder(tree.root, new ArrayList<IDancer>());
        } catch(NullPointerException n) {return new ArrayList<IDancer>();}
    }
}
```

Tree.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Tree {
    public Node root = null;
    public IDancer male(IDancer female) {
        Node current = search(genKey(female));
        Node tmp = succsessor(current);
        while (!tmp.isMale()) {
            tmp = succsessor(tmp);
        } return tmp.isMale() ? tmp.dancer : null;
    }
    public IDancer female(IDancer male) {
        Node current = search(genKey(male));
        Node tmp = predecessor(current);
        while (tmp.isMale()) {
            tmp = predecessor(tmp);
        } return  tmp.isMale() ? null : tmp.dancer;
    }
    public Node minimum() {return minimum(this.root);}
    private Node minimum(Node node) {
        if (node.hasLeft())
            return minimum(node.left);
        else return node;
    }
    public Node maximum() {return maximum(this.root);}
    public Node maximum(Node node) {
        if (node.hasRight())
            return maximum(node.right);
        else return node;
    }
    public double genKey(IDancer d) {
        return Double.parseDouble(d.getHeight() +  (d.isMale() ? "0." : "1.") + d.getID());
    }
    private Node search(double key, Node current) {
        if (current.key == key) return current;
        if (current.key > key
                && current.hasLeft())
            return search(key, current.left);
        if (current.key < key
                && current.hasRight())
            return search(key, current.right);
        return null;
    }
    public Node search(double key) {return search(key, this.root);}
    public void insert(IDancer d) {
        Node dancer = new Node(d);
        Node y = null;
        if (root == null) {
            this.root = dancer;
            return;
        }
        Node x = this.root;
        while (x != null) {
            y = x;
            if (dancer.key < x.key) x = x.left;
            else x = x.right;
        } dancer.parent = y;
        if (y == null) this.root = dancer;
        else {
            if (dancer.key < y.key) y.left = dancer;
            else y.right = dancer;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<IDancer> inorder(Node node, ArrayList<IDancer> output) {
        if (node.hasLeft())
            inorder(node.left, output);
        output.add(node.dancer);
        if (node.hasRight())
            inorder(node.right, output);
        return output;
    }
    public void remove(IDancer d) {
        Node z = search(genKey(d)); //toRemove
        Node y = null; //replacer
        Node x = null;
        if (!z.hasLeft() || !z.hasRight()) 
            y = z;
        else y = succsessor(z);
        if (y.hasLeft())
            x = y.left;
        else x = y.right;
        if (x != null)
            x.parent = y.parent;
        if (!y.hasParent())
            this.root = x;
        else if (y == y.parent.left)
            y.parent.left = x;
        else y.parent.right = x;
        if (y != z)
            z.dancer = y.dancer;
        y = null;
    }
    private Node succsessor(Node n) {
        if (n.hasRight())
            return minimum(n.right);
        Node tmp = n.hasParent() ? n.parent : null;
        while (tmp != null && n == tmp.right) {
            n = tmp;
            tmp = tmp.parent;
        } return tmp;
    }
    private Node predecessor(Node n) {
        if (n.hasLeft())
            return maximum(n.left);
        Node tmp = n.hasParent() ? n.parent : null;
        while (tmp != null && n == tmp.left) {
            n = tmp;
            tmp = tmp.parent;
        } return tmp;
    }
}
```